# ios: AFNetworking Specify base url in info.plist

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, info.plist

Hi i am a new developer testing ios app development. I have an API server set up and I am using AFNetworking to communicate with the API server. Is there a way I can specify the url of the API server in info.plist or a common config file somewhere so that I can use it through out the project
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can

you can create header file and set base url in header file.

```
#define API_URL @"http://www.sample.com"
```

Also, you can create .plist file and set url and get url from .plist

Comment: I want to use it through out the project. So to define it in a header file wont be sufficient I guess. I will check the usage of plist. thanks.

Comment: you can set it in header file and use it in through out the project.